# How create ticks charts in anycharts

Tags: javascript, charts, stock, anychart

I learn AnyCharts library and i need to create a tick chart (Its specificity is that it shows every change in price. Thanks to this, it is possible to observe the quotations of a given instrument in the most accurate way. If, for example, the transaction price is 1 point higher than the previous transaction, then the tick chart will immediately jump one point higher on the chart, but if the transaction has a price higher than the previous transaction by three points, then the tick chart will also "shoot" three points higher.) in case when i have a date something like this:

```
var data =[ [new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 31, 0),511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
[new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 31, 1),211.53, 414.98, 405.79, 406.40],
[new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 31, 1),512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 207.34],
[new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 31, 3),511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 106.47],
[new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 31, 4),511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
[new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 34, 32, 4),111.53, 114.98, 105.79, 106.40],
[new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 34, 32, 5),511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40]]
```

I want to show a every single point - without compression points from the same time (I'm afraid that's all I can do).

My goal is chart like this: [image: Ticks chart]

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, the Stock chart with Step Line series is the best choice. Check [the article](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Series/Step_Line), it describes how to create and adjust such a chart.